# How should I solve this differential equation?

Tags: differential-equations

I am trying to solve the differential equation below. But I couldn't find it. $$y''+2xy=3,$$ $y(0)=0$ and $y(2)=3,98 $.
It looks like a linear differential equation, but I couldn't find where I'm making a mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but I couldn't find where I'm making a mistake.

We also can't see where you made a mistake because you did not show what you did. May be you had some syntax error?

It is linear, but it is has coefficient which are not constant (`x`). These are much harder to solve that linear ode's with constant coefficients.

I assumed `3,98` means `3.98`. When using `DSolve` it is better to give it exact numbers.

```
ClearAll[y, x]
ode = y''[x] + 3 x y[x] == 3;
ic = {y[0] == 0, y[2] == 389/100};
sol = DSolve[{ode, ic}, y[x], x]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Maple gives similar answer, but leaves integrals unresolved:

```
 dsolve([diff(y(x),x$2)+3*x*y(x)=3,y(0)=0,y(2)=389/100],y(x))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you dear Nasser.